# ArcGIS Enterprise GeoEvent installation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise, geoevent-processor

I want to make sure that am understanding the correct workflow for installing and configuring the GeoEvent server.

ArcGIS Enterprise version: 10.9.1

We have the following set up :

On Machine A, we have ArcGIS Server, ArcGIS Portal & ArcGIS DataStore & on Machine B, we have 2 WebAdaptor for ArcGIS Server and Portal.

We now want to install GeoEvent Server on Machine C, and according to the following docs, it is mentioned that we need to install ArcGIS Server first and then geoevent server.

- https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.9.1/windows/system-requirements.htm
- https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/geoevent/10.9.1/deploy/base-geoevent-server-deployment.htm
- https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-geoevent-server-questions/install-geoevent-server-on-separate-m...

In the [following](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/geoevent/10.9.1/deploy/base-geoevent-server-deployment.htm) doc it is also mentioned that when installing ArcGIS Server on second machine it should be licensed with GeoEvent Server license. Am attaching a screenshot as well.

[image]

However, when I follow this workflow and try to create a new site, I get the error "Failed to create the site. Querying for licenses failed". Hence, my questions are:

1. Why exactly am I getting this error? Do I need to authorize ArcGIS
   Server first with a Server Std. or Advanced License and then with a
   GeoEvent license?
2. When configuring ArcGIS Server, should I create a new site, or can I
   join an existing site, as in the [following](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-geoevent-server-questions/install-geoevent-server-on-separate-machine/td-p/630868) link, its mentioned that
   a new site needs to be created; otherwise, geoevent might not work
   properly; however, it's a bit old so wanted to know if there has
   been any change.

Comment: One question per Question, please. A bullet list will generate close votes.